# Combinatoric idendity proof Validation ,n choose k, k-subsets from n-element's - feedback check

Tags: combinatorics

i want to validate my proof , thank you for your time .

**INTRO**

we take $k$ to be the greatest element and we chose the smallest k that can be depending on n and how many element's we would need (for exemple if i need 13-element from 100-element set A than i will choose first k to be 12)

**The identity :**
$\binom{k+1}{m+1}=  \sum_{i=m}^k\binom {i}{m}$

$k,m,n\in Z^+$

**THE PROOF**

$k,t,a,n\in Z^+$

$k=t$ , where t is the smallest k as we discussed in the intro . 
then assuming $|A|$=n ,we want to choose some m-element's from $|A|/\left \{  k\right \}$ that is
$\left \{a_1,a_2,a_3...a_t-1|\forall a_1,a_2,a_3...a_t-1[a_i<t\right\}$  so we get :$\binom{t}{t-1}$ 
next
k=t+1 than:  $\left \{a_1,a_2,a_3...a_(t-1+1)|\forall a_1,a_2,a_3...a_(t-1+1)[a_i<t\right\}$ and $\binom{t}{t}$ and so on until , $k=t+a=n-1$ $\left \{a_1,a_2,a_3...a_(n-1)|\forall a_1,a_2,a_3...a_(n-1)[a_i<t\right\}$ and : $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ when $  \sum_{i=m}^k\binom {i}{m}$ where summation goes from $t$ till $n-1=r$

is it a valid proof for first course in discrete mathematics, and is it ok ? thank you, just wanted built proof by myself.

Comment: Before you start the proof, please state the identity you are proving.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification , i added it

Comment: The identity should have only one equals sign, and you should specify what $k$ and $m$ are (nonnegative integers?).

Comment: Thank you , added it

Comment: You should write the summation indices explicitly, like $\sum_{i=0}^r$.

Comment: Thank you , added

Comment: You are getting closer, but the left hand side depends on $k$, so you cannot use $k$ as a summation index on the right hand side.

Comment: understood,changed

Comment: Sorry, still not correct. The summand does not depend on the summation index, and the right hand side depends on $n$ while the left hand side does not.

Comment: don't understand ... , but in my class there isn't so much specificity

Comment: I suspect that you want $\binom{k+1}{m+1}= \sum_{i=m}^k\binom {i}{m}$, which is known as the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: oh wow, first, i didnt know the name of the identity so it';s great to hear from you about it, second , thank you for the clarification , i really missed your final point . but now i understand the critical point. thank you again